# My choice, you can’t refuse

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> Take part, you may win
>   Go fast if you choose
>   Some see me in your skin
>   My choice, you can’t refuse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer might be:

> Race.

```
Take part, you may win  
Go fast if you choose
```

> A race could mean a competition between runners, horses, vehicles, etc. to see which is the fastest in covering a set course.

```
Some see me in your skin  
My choice, you can’t refuse
```

> Race could also mean each of the major divisions of humankind, having distinct physical characteristics, one being skin colour.